# Create a function that calculates x to the power of P (both x and P are integers)

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to create a function that calculates `x^P`.
The function needs to work only for integer inputs (no fractions).
The output can be fractional.

Two days for a test to get into a coding course, so your quick answers will be appreciated.

My current progress is this:

```js
function powerBy(x, P) {
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.abs(P); i = i + 1) {
    if (P > 0 && P % 2 === 0 && x != 0 || P > 0 && P % 2 === 1 && x > 0) {
      // pink
      x = x * x;
    } else if (P < 0 && P % 2 === 0 && x != 0 || P < 0 && P % 2 === 1 && x > 0) {
      // orange
      x = 1 / (x * x);
    } else if (P % 2 === 1 && x < 0) {
      // blue marker 
      x = -1 / (x * x);
    } else if (P > 0 && P % 2 === 1 && x < 0) {
      // blue pen- first if can aplly as well
      x = (x * x);
    } else if (P !== 0 && P % 2 === 0 && x < 0) {
      // yellow
      x = 1;
    } else {
      return "p is 0 and x is 0 = mistake";
    }
    return x
  }
}
console.log(powerBy(2, 2)); // should output 4
console.log(powerBy(4, 4)); // should output 256
console.log(powerBy(2, -1)); // should output 0.5
```

Comment: please add the wanted result (or some more use cases ...) as well.

Comment: i am not sure what you mean.  for "console.log(powerBy(2,2))" i want 4. For "console.log(powerBy(2,-1))" i want 0.5.

Comment: Are you typing o instead of 0 ?

Comment: yes i am positive it is zero :)

Comment: What errors do you get when you try to run this? One thing I immediately see is that `elseif` is not defined in javascript (you must use `else if`)

Comment: At google chrome developer  tools it gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {".
Didn't matter if it's else if or elseif

Comment: @SaarSeri, that is because of that syntax error with your else if, even if all of your syntaxes are fixed, it still lacks the logic to handle the neg power. Here is the fiddle with all your syntaxes fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/jeyz2f7h/

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're just trying to write your own `Math.pow()`? You're doing a lot of complicated things and I'm not sure why. Are there some particular constraints you're working with?

```
const powerBy = (x, P) => {
    const absP = Math.abs(P);
    let result = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < absP; i++) {
        result *= x;
    }
    if (P < 0) {
        result = 1 / result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I think something like this should be sufficient if a linear time complexity is OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to create a recursive solution, I offer:

```
// p is assumed to be integer
const powerBy = (x, p) => {
    if (p === 0) {
        return 1
    }
    if (p === -1) {
        return 1 / x
    }
    if (p === 1) {
        return x
    }
    return p < 0 ? (1 / x) * powerBy(x, p + 1) : x * powerBy(x, p - 1)
}
```

Otherwise, you can convert it to the equivalent iterative loop.
Need help with that? :)